# Is there an AsValue instance for nested Vectors of Aeson Values?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to get the feel of `aeson` package. Am I using its `Lens` API incorrectly?

```
> :t bt ^? _Array
bt ^? _Array :: Maybe (vector-0.10.12.2:Data.Vector.Vector Value)

> :t bt ^? _Array . nth 0 . _Array

<interactive>:1:16:
    No instance for (AsValue
                       (vector-0.10.12.2:Data.Vector.Vector Value))
      arising from a use of ‘nth’
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘nth 0’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘nth 0 . _Array’
    In the second argument of ‘(^?)’, namely ‘_Array . nth 0 . _Array’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `nth` which is a combinator designed to make it easier to work when you are directly traversing a JSON value. However, you're working with a vector of values. In this case, you should use `ix 0` rather than `nth 0`.